# How do I open the Command Options in Battlefield 3 for the PS3?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

I play on the pc and can bring up the commands to spot enemies, call for ammo, etc but my son plays on the PS3 and we can't figure out how to do those same actions. Anyone got an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

[image]
What you're referring to is called [**commo rose**](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Commo_Rose) and is brought up on PC using <kbd>Q</kbd> button. <kbd>Back</kbd> button on X360 and <kbd>Select</kbd> button PS3 have same role, but as of now it's **only limited to [spotting](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Spotting)** (which also works as a single context dependent command, for example spotting friendly support will ask him for ammo).

It's been speculated by DICE developers [that it might get console support](http://mp1st.com/2011/12/23/bf3-dev-responds-to-over-powered-famas-operation-metro-on-cq-and-more/), but apparently [that did not happen](http://mp1st.com/2012/03/26/battlefield-3-armored-kill-map-sizes-consoles-will-not-get-commo-rose-no-more-specialized-assignments-and-more/) and most likely will not ever happen.

> “no plans to add it on consoles where other automated systems are in
>   place.”

Comment: It is also used to call for ammo/health, vehicle pickup. But this is automatic, and will only happen when you are pointed at support/medic or a vehicle with an open seat.

Comment: Sad, it seems like they've disabled a pretty valuable component.  Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure these commands are only available on the PC. If it is through the developer console, then you will not be able to access this on PS3/Xbox360 systems.

Comment: So no ability to spot or give commands?  That kinda sucks.

Comment: @Mitch Afraid so. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The DualShock3's SELECT button is what you need... It's the only SPOT/Communication button... If you press SELECT looking to the enemy, it will SPOT... If the teammate is playing as Support guy, look him and press SELECT then you'll ask him for ammo... If Engineer and look for a damaged tank, press SELECT then you'll offer repair, etc.etc.etc... The situation changes the function of the button...